# Sorting dictionary values according to the values of one of the keys ckeys

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key-value

I receive a dictionary with two keys, that has lists of lists as values.
Example:

```
dict = {'points' : [[2,1],[3,4], [5,6],[7,8]], 'ids':[[2], [1], [3], [0]]}
```

Each point has an id associated with it, ex: point [2,1] has id[2], point[3,4] has id[1] etc .

I need to sort the points in respect to each id. So the ouput I need is something like this

```
dict = {'points' : [[7,8],[3,4], [2,1],[5,6]], 'ids':[[0], [1], [2], [3]]}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Python can do this in one line:

```
>>> d = {'points' : [[2,1],[3,4], [5,6],[7,8]], 'ids':[[2], [1], [3], [0]]}
>>> d['ids'], d['points'] = zip(*sorted(zip(d['ids'], d['points'])))
>>> d
{'points': ([7, 8], [3, 4], [2, 1], [5, 6]), 'ids': ([0], [1], [2], [3])}
```

The *zip* steps brings the *ids* and *points* together pairwise.  The *sorted* step orders by the *id* which is the first element of each pair.  The `zip(*s)` step splits the *ids* and *points* and points back into separate sequences.

Note the internal data types have been converted from lists to tuples.  If this isn't desired, you can call *list* to convert them back.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use builtin names as variable names!

```py
data = {'points' : [[2,1],[3,4], [5,6],[7,8]], 'ids':[[2], [1], [3], [0]]}
ids, points = zip(*sorted(zip(data['ids'], data['points'])))
print({
    'points': list(points),
    'ids': list(ids),
})
# output: {'points': [[7, 8], [3, 4], [2, 1], [5, 6]], 'ids': [[0], [1], [2], [3]]}
```

First you create `zip` object - it represents 'pairs' (or n-tuples if more arguments are given) of objects, so each point is bound to id. Then `sorted()` sorts them by first element, which is id (we could pass additional `key` argument to keep order same). Finally we split sorted results back to two arrays (applying `zip` again restores initial configuration), assign them to variables and create required dictionary.

Comment: You might want to enhance your answer by explaining the solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, the output is a bit different, it's not what you reported. Specifically, both points and ids are tuples of lists, not lists of lists.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Thanks! You're right, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d['ids'], d['points'] = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(d['ids'], d['points']))))
```

Please don't use built in function names (such as `dict`) to name your variables. here I used `d` instead.

As suggested by Kelly in the comments below, this is also an option:

```
d['ids'][:], d['points'][:] = zip(*sorted(zip(d['ids'], d['points'])))
```

Comment: Could also assign into the existing lists, then you don't need the map.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for your comment. Not sure what you mean though. Could you show me the code? Or feel free to edit the answer directly (and take credits)

Comment: Assign to `d['ids'][:]` instead of `d['ids']`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh that makes much sense, right!! Thanks